# Checking to see if strings in one column matches the abbreviated form of the strings in another column

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a large data frame "df" with 2 columns:

```
**column1**                             **column2**
The City of New York                     TCNY
The Land of the Free                     TLF
Stellar Stars Basketball Program         SSBP
Center for Life Sciences                 CLS
Children's Hospital of Los Angeles       CHLA
New York Yankees                         NY
etc                                      etc
```

I've done some research and saw that you could use mapply to do a function on two columns at the same time but I'm uncertain what function I would do. I was thinking doing something where a function checks all the capital letters in the strings of column1 and checks if those capital letters exist in column2 but really unsure how.. Any help would be great! Thank you so much!

Comment: What kind of output are you hoping for?  A vector of yes/no?  If you want to subset or filter your data, I suggest using `dplyr`'s `mutate` function in conjunction with some `regex` expressions like `[[:upper:]]` (more regex found here: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of what I think you might be trying to achieve (on a subset of the rows you've shown in your question):

```
df <- data.frame(
  col_1 = c("The City of New York", "The Land of the Free", "New York Yankees"),
  col_2 = c("TCNY", "TLF", "NY")
)

> df
                 col_1 col_2
1 The City of New York  TCNY
2 The Land of the Free   TLF
3     New York Yankees    NY

# Add a third column indicating whether the capitalised letters of the first
# column are equal to the strings in the second
df$col_3 <- unlist(apply(df, 1, function(x) gsub("[^A-Z]", "", x[1]) == x[2]))

> df
                 col_1 col_2 col_3
1 The City of New York  TCNY  TRUE
2 The Land of the Free   TLF  TRUE
3     New York Yankees    NY FALSE
```

Above I'm using `gsub` to remove any characters that aren't upper case from the first column values, then comparing them to the second column in an `apply` statement, which is operating on each row of the dataframe. Then I'm using `unlist` to convert the result from a list to a vector, which can be stored in the third column of the dataframe `df`.

Answer (score 0):

Using base r

```
   transform(dat,correctABBV=x<-gsub("[^A-Z]","",column1),check=x==column2)
                             column1 column2 correctABBV check
1               The City of New York    TCNY        TCNY  TRUE
2               The Land of the Free     TLF         TLF  TRUE
3   Stellar Stars Basketball Program    SSBP        SSBP  TRUE
4           Center for Life Sciences     CLS         CLS  TRUE
5 Children's Hospital of Los Angeles    CHLA        CHLA  TRUE
6                   New York Yankees      NY         NYY FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach for you. I was not sure if you wanted to keep `etc` as an abbreviation or not. At the moment, I treat it as an abbreviation. First, I wanted to create abbreviations based on the first column. I checked how many words exist in each string using `stri_count()`. When the answer is TRUE to the logical condition, I used `gsub()` to extract capital letters. When the answer is FALSE to the logical condition, I added elements in `mycol1` to `abb`. Finally, I checked if elements in `abb` and `mycol2` are the same or not and created `check`.

```
mydf <- data.frame(mycol1 = c("The City of New York", "The Land of the Free", "Stellar Stars Basketball Program",
                              "Center for Life Sciences", "Children's Hospital of Los Angeles", "New York Yankees", "etc"),
                   mycol2 = c("TCNY", "TLF", "SSBP", "CLS", "CHLA", "NY", "etc"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    

library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

mutate(mydf,
       abb = if_else(stri_count(mycol1, regex = "\\w+") > 1,
                     gsub(x = mycol1, pattern = "[^A-Z]",replacement = ""),
                     mycol1),
       check = abb == mycol2)

                              mycol1 mycol2  abb check
1               The City of New York   TCNY TCNY  TRUE
2               The Land of the Free    TLF  TLF  TRUE
3   Stellar Stars Basketball Program   SSBP SSBP  TRUE
4           Center for Life Sciences    CLS  CLS  TRUE
5 Children's Hospital of Los Angeles   CHLA CHLA  TRUE
6                   New York Yankees     NY  NYY FALSE
7                                etc    etc  etc  TRUE
```